# How can I calculate how long ffmpeg will take to encode this file?

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I calculate how long ffmpeg will take to encode this file?

```
root@ubuntu-c-32-64gib-lon1-01:~# ls -l brs.mp4  --block-size=M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 626M Apr 27 08:24 brs.mp4
root@ubuntu-c-32-64gib-lon1-01:~#

root@ubuntu-c-32-64gib-lon1-01:~# ffmpeg -i 'brs.mp4' -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 theoutputfile.mp4

...
frame= 2069 fps=208 q=-1.0 Lsize=   15192kB time=00:01:09.43 bitrate=1792.5kbits/s speed=6.98x
video:14589kB audio:543kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.399940%
..
```

Comment: Because encoding speed (relative to realtime, `speed=6.98x`) can vary greatly depending on the actual video contents, I don’t think this is possible with reasonable accuracy.

Comment: @DanielB A)so does 6.98x mean that a 15 minute video will take  15/6.98 i.e.  2.14 minutes?  i.e. 2min 8sec ? (Assuming constant speed)?

Comment: @DanielB B)Likewise, a speed of 0.33x would mean it'd take three times longer to encode it than the length of the actual video?

Comment: Yes, that’s correct.